# Why doesn't my Jenkins job use P4 tickets?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have multiple Jenkins jobs, and have found that one of them is failing, as it doesn't appear to be using P4 tickets.

Here is the start of the log for `QuickBuild` which works fine (Note this is the log from the perforce plugin, before my build script itself starts running)

```
Building in workspace E:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\QuickBuild
Using master perforce client: QuickBuild
[QuickBuild] $ p4 -P 10F4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC784 workspace -o QuickBuild
Last build changeset: 55479
[QuickBuild] $ p4 -P 10F4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC784 changes -s submitted -m 1 //QuickBuild/...
[QuickBuild] $ p4 -P 10F4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC784 -s changes -s submitted //QuickBuild/...@55480,@55489
[QuickBuild] $ p4 -P 10F4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC784 describe -s 55489
```

You can see the -P 10F4.... ticket in the log, and the value of `%P4TICKET%` is available to the script being launched to perform the build.

However, in the failing `ThoroughBuild` job, the log is as so

```
Building on master in workspace E:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ThoroughBuild
Using master perforce client: ThoroughBuild
[ThoroughBuild] $ p4 workspace -o ThoroughBuild
Last build changeset: 56725
[ThoroughBuild] $ p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //ThoroughBuild/...
[ThoroughBuild] $ p4 -s changes -s submitted //ThoroughBuild/...@56726,@56727
[ThoroughBuild] $ p4 describe -s 56727
```

Note the lack of the -P  parameter in the log.  `%P4TICKET%` is not set in the environment, so the build script fails (since it tries to check out files)

This behaviour is consistent (QuickBuild always uses tickets, ThoroughBuild never does.)

Can anyone tell me what I need to configure in the `ThoroughBuild` job to make it use tickets?  As far as I can tell, the relevant configuration sections for both jobs are identical, only varying in their Perforce workspace mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Tickets are stored in home directory of current user. If you run Jenkins with different permissions that may be a problem because it can't find proper tickets to login.
You can check with P4USER to check if you are really using account you defined. Similar with port and password.

Answer (score 0):

The Slave agent on which ThoroughBuild job is running might be having a perforce instance already running. Kill all the perforce instances running on the slave agent and start a fresh build. It should show the perforce ticket in the console now and you can use that in the Build step.